# change font size after decimal point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, opencart

I am working with an Opencart E-Commerce website, I need to customize product price font size,
for example:
`product price: $ 250.50` i need to set font size for `$ = 16px;` `250 = 22px;`  `.50 = 14px;`

How can I set different font sizes for a single amount..???

this s my dynamic php code that display price text to my product page:

```
<span class="price"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></span>
```

my product list page not a single product with price, there is a lots of product with price list.

thanks for any help, if anybody asked the same question before here, please share with me those links...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$.each($('.price'), function(){
var price = $(this).html();
$(this).html(price.replace(/(\D*)(\d*\.)(\d*)/,'<span style="font-size:16px;">$1</span><span style="font-size:22px;">$2</span><span style="font-size:14px;">$3</span>'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gr8x5/10/

Comment: thanks for your answer, its working for single product.... but when tried multiple product lists same page, i got result first product price repeat wit all other product price... can you check your example..??

Comment: @kuraiinazuma... thank you  its working now... one more question, my site have 2 currencies, USD $, and Kuwait Dinar KD, how can i set both of them this code.? your above answer only working with USD $.. i need Kuwait KD too... any idea...? thanks

Comment: Great code. You can also make it dynamic: `'$1$2<span style="font-size: smaller;">$3</span>'` (or use `70%` or so.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick and dirty example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .dollar_sign { font-size: 16px; }
        .dollars { font-size: 22px; }
        .cents { font-size: 14px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<?
    $product = array('price' => '245.50');
    $part    = explode('.', $product['price']);
?>
    <span class="dollar_sign">$</span><span class="dollars"><?= $part[0] ?></span>.<span class="cents"><?= $part[1] ?></span>   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this code

```
var pri = $(".price").text();
var sig = pri.split(" ");
var dol_smbl = "<span style='font-size:16px;'>" + sig[0] + "</span>";
var digits = sig[1].split(".");
befr_dec = "<span style='font-size:22px;'>" + digits[0] + "</span>";
aftr_dec = "<span style='font-size:14px;'>." + digits[1] + "</span>";
$(".price").html(dol_smbl + " " + befr_dec + aftr_dec);
```

Answer (score 3):

Can be beautifully done with a little css and regex. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vw8Ys/)

the HTML :

```
<span class="price">$250.50</span>
```

the css :

```
.currency { font-size:16px; }
.number { font-size:22px; }
.decimal { font-size:14px; }
```

the javascript :

```
 var price = $('span.price').text();  
    var pArry = price.match(/^(\$)(\d+)(\.\d+)?/);    
    var new_span = $(
        '<span class="currency">' + pArry[1] + '</span>' +
        '<span class="number">' + pArry[2] + '</span>' +
        '<span class="decimal">' + pArry[3] + '</span>');
    $('span.price').replaceWith(new_span);
```

Done

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
var my_price = $(".price").text();
var dol_smbl = "<span style='font-size:16px;'>"+my_price[0]+"</span>";
var price = split(" ",my_price);
var price_arr = split('.',price[1]);
befr_dec = "<span style='font-size:22px;'>"+price_arr[0]+"</span>";
aftr_dec = "<span style='font-size:14px;'>."+price_arr[1]+"</span>";
$(".price").html(dol_smbl + " " + befr_dec  + aftr_dec);
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to split up that var? Look at the php function `explode()`.

http://php.net/manual/de/function.explode.php

Answer (score 1):

You can try this generic approach

```
$('.price').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        txt = $this.text(),
        splt = txt.split('.'),
        spltFirst = splt.pop(),
        spn3 = $('<span/>', {
            text: spltFirst,
                'class': 'font-small'
        }),
        spltSecond = splt.pop(),
        spn1 = $('<span/>', {
            text: spltSecond.substring(0, spltSecond.lastIndexOf('$') + 1),
                'class': 'font-medium'
        }),
        spn2 = $('<span/>', {
            text: spltSecond.substring(spltSecond.lastIndexOf('$') + 1) + '.',
                'class': 'font-big'
        });
    $this.text('');
    $this.append(spn1).append(spn2).append(spn3);
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y56QP/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use different span element for those three different segments and set class for them individually to assign different font styles. Basically spans are inline element, so you dont need to worry about its placement.

For example:

After rendering your markup should be like this,

```
<span class="price">
    <span class="currencySymbol">$</span>
    <span class="amt1">250</span>
    <span class="amt2">.50</span>
</span>
```

then in CSS:

```
.currencySymbol{ font-size:16px; } 
.amt1{ font-size:22px; } 
.amt2{ font-size:14px; }
```

Comment: its not static text, its dynamically generated price text... see my question

Comment: @mans well, i dont have any ideas about php, you can make your php code to render your html like i given. I think this would be cleaner in your case.

Answer (score 0):

A possible simple dynamic way using only split().

This will wrap decimals in a `<small>` tag on each element having a class `format` .

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".format").forEach((e) => {
  let txt = e.innerHTML.split(".")
  e.innerHTML = txt[0] + ".<small>" + txt[1] + "</small>"
})
```

```css
.format {font-size:3rem}
small {font-size:1.4rem}
```

```html
<div class="format">34454.545432</div>
<div class="format">0.0000463533</div>
<div class="format"><mark>Hello</mark> -8765.9876</div>
```