# Remove dot from text generated in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I found a code that i need for a site but it is not exactly what i want (
[change font size after decimal point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17162945/change-font-size-after-decimal-point)).

So i have:

```js
$.each($('.price'), function() {
  var price = $(this).html();
  $(this).html(price.replace(/(\D*)(\d*\.)(\d*)/, '<span style="font-size:16px;">$1</span><span style="font-size:22px;">$2</span><span style="font-size:14px;">$3</span>'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='price'>$ 270.30</div>
<div class='price'>eur 64.60</div>
<div class='price'>€ 290.12</div>
<div class='price'>dollars 240.50</div>
```

The problem is that i want to have the value without the dot in the end, like: $ 270 30

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The problem is that I want to have the value without the dot in the end, like: $ 270 30

Then remove `\.` from the second capture group. Change this:

```
/(\D*)(\d*\.)(\d*)/
```

To this:

```
/(\D*)(\d*)\.(\d*)/
```

Updated Example:

```js
$.each($('.price'), function() {
  var price = $(this).html();
  $(this).html(price.replace(/(\D*)(\d*)\.(\d*)/, '<span style="font-size:16px;">$1</span><span style="font-size:22px;">$2</span> <span style="font-size:14px;">$3</span>'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='price'>$ 270.30</div>
<div class='price'>eur 64.60</div>
<div class='price'>€ 290.12</div>
<div class='price'>dollars 240.50</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't understand so well the regex part so that's why i didn't get it from the start. Thank you again!