# (Jquery) Change font size after decimal point for (javascript dynamically generated) numbers

Tags: html, jquery, replace, each

I was looking for a way to change the digits after the decimal point. I have found [this useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17163283/15151582). The code there is:

```
$.each($('.price'), function(){
var price = $(this).html();
$(this).html(price.replace(/(\D*)(\d*\.)(\d*)/,'<span style="font-size:16px;">$1</span><span style="font-size:22px;">$2</span><span style="font-size:14px;">$3</span>'));
});
```

Unfortunately, my numbers are also generated by javascript. So they basically do not exist in the page code. In other words, in the browser's console I can see the

```
<span class="price">$ 270.30</span>
```

if I right click on the price and then inspect, but not when I use Ctrl+U and search for it.

The error displayed in the console is

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'each')*

Is there a way to make this code work for dynamically generated prices? Or maybe other solution to change the size of the digits?

Thank you.

Comment: So you do not have jQuery? It is saying `$` is undefined

Comment: I have. And the error is Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'each'), not undefined.